# NVS and 3D infrared from 2D infrared images

Tags: model

I have about 24,000 2D grayscale infrared images with different orientations and I've been trying to find a way (a model) to generate novel views and 3D models using solely the 2D images as input. The 2D images don't have any information about the sensors/camera (pose, intrinsics). Any suggestions on how to go about this task would be more than appreciated. Note: I don't have matching RGB images.

I tried a NeRF approach that didn't work. An attempt with COLMAP was also unsuccessful.

Comment: Pls read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask